# WPF DatePicker UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged not working

Tags: wpf, updatesourcetrigger

I am using MVVM and want to enable a button on text change of datepicker control..

XAML Code:
Binding on DatePicker

```
SelectedDate="{Binding InactiveDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
DisplayDate="{Binding InactiveDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Binding on Button:

```
<Button Margin="10" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
```

View Model Code:
I am using a DelegateCommand for button click

View Model Delegate Initialization

```
SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSubmitRequested, AllowSubmit, Controller);
```

The AllowSubmit implementation

```
private bool AllowSubmit()
{
    return InactiveDate != null;
}
```

InactiveDate Property implementation

```
    public DateTime? InactiveDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _inactiveDate;
        }

        set
        {
            _inactiveDate = value;
            SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InactiveDate"));
        }
    }
```

`SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` should enable the button once I enter any character on DateTimePicker but it is not happening.

Answer (score -1):

Selected Date property does not work properly. I might be a bit late now, but you can use CurrentDateTimeText property of RadDatePicker